# How to specify supported http operation for a resource in json-ld?

Tags: rest, json-ld, http-method, hydra-core

I'm new to JSON-LD and I was wondering if there is any way of specifying supported operation of a resource in JSON-LD without using Hydra's **supportedOperation** or **supportedProperty**.
Is there any way to specify the context something like :

```
    {
    "@context" : {
    "@vocab" : "http://www.schema.org/",
    "data" : "object",
    "id" :"Number",
    "name" : "alternateName",
    "full_name" : "name",
    "links" : {
        "@id" : "URL",
        "@type" : "collection"
    },
    "href" : "URL",
    "rel" : "relatedTo",
    "operation" : [
     {
      "href" : "http://example.com/resources/1/anotherresources/2",
      "method" : "POST",
      "expects" :[parameter list],
      "required" : [list of mandatory arguments],
      "fixed value" : [list of argument with fixed value for a resource]
     }
     ]
   }
```

Any guidance would be of great help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't specify it in the context. What you can do, however, is to bind an operation to a property in a Hydra `ApiDocumentation` ([example 10 in the spec](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/#documenting-a-web-api))  and [reference it via an HTTP Link header](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/#discovering-a-hydra-powered-web-api).